# Can I specify ID's on elements within a keyframe to reduce CSS using sass?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm sure this is somewhat of a newbie question, but I have just recently started implementing sass in my projects and I would like to know if there is an easier/more efficient way to make this code happen using sass - thanks for your help :) .

I want to group such that I can identify the 100% keyframe's width by ID instead of rewriting the animation line and the keyframe for each.

```
span.underline {
  display:block;
  width:calc(100% - 130px);
  height:2px;
  background-color:transparent;
  position:absolute;
  left:41px;
}

#topNav .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover > span.underline#acctInfo {
  animation: acctInfo 0.3s ease-out forwards;
   background: #FFF;
}

@keyframes acctInfo {
  0% { 
    width:0;
  }
  100% { 
    width:calc(100% - 130px);
  }
}

#topNav .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover > span.underline#replenish {
  animation: replenish 0.3s ease-out forwards;
   background: #FFF;
}

@keyframes replenish {
  0% { 
    width:0;
  }
  100% { 
    width:calc(100% - 60px);
  }
}

#topNav .navbar-nav>li>a:hover > span.underline#more {
  animation: more 0.3s ease-out forwards;
   background: #FFF;
}

@keyframes more {
  0% { 
    width:0;
  }
  100% { 
    width:calc(100% - 65px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't easy, I find no way to extract the id selector. The most I have archieve is a mixin wich I passed the `id` name as an argument. I also try to get the `id` from `$name` variable to add inside the mixin and no need write in the selector but I get the selector twice (with and without `id`).

**SASS**

```
@mixin animation($name) {
  animation: $name 0.3s ease-out forwards;
  @keyframes #{$name} {
    0% {
      width: 0;
    }
    100% {
      @if $name=="replenish" {
        width: calc(100% - 60px);
      }
      @else if $name=="more" {
        width: calc(100% - 65px);
      }
    }
  }
}

#topNav .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover > span.underline#replenish {
  @include animation(replenish);
  background: #FFF;
}

#topNav .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover > span.underline#more {
  @include animation(more);
  background: red;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
#topNav .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover > span.underline#replenish {
  animation: replenish 0.3s ease-out forwards;
  background: #FFF;
}
@keyframes replenish {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
  }
}
#topNav .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover > span.underline#more {
  animation: more 0.3s ease-out forwards;
  background: red;
}
@keyframes more {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: calc(100% - 65px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on what blonfu suggested, personally, I'd add a second argument for the width value so that you can reuse the mixin without having to create more if/else cases:

```
@mixin animation($name, $width) {
  animation: $name 0.3s ease-out forwards;

  @keyframes #{$name} {
    0% {
      width: 0;
    }
    100% {
        width: calc(100% - $width);
    }
  }

}
```